# Existe alguma função que procura se uma palavra existe no texto?

Tags: php, string

No PHP existe alguma `função` que faz a verificação de palavras em textos, exemplo:

```
A camila morreu de diabete.
```

Quero criar uma função procurando a palavra `morreu`, para depois que encontrar jogar num `if` o resultado, ficando mais ou menos assim:

```
if (função == 'morreu') { echo 'OK'; } else { echo 'FAIL'; }
```

Existe alguma função?

Comment: Verificação é um termos muito genérico, precisa dizer o que deseja fazer. Quer saber se a palavra está contida no texto?

Comment: Isso, desejo saber se a palavra está no `texto`, para depois conseguir criar uma `IF` com ela em si.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tem a [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php). Ou [`stripos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) se desejar ignorar a caixa das letras. Em alguns casos pode querer procurar pela fim, talvez por performance, com [`strrpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php).

Estas funções retornam `false` se o texto procurado não estiver no texto completo, ou retorna a posição da primeira ocorrência do texto se ele for achado. Então pode testar isto, algo assim:

```
if (strpos('A camila morreu de diabete', 'morreu') !== false) { echo 'OK'; } else { echo 'FAIL'; }
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/String/Contains.php).